# foundation 5.2.2 topbar dropdown not working for mobile device

Tags: javascript, html, zurb-foundation

I am trying to develop my site with foundation dropdown. when i see reponsive size from pc browser it's working
(not 1st time:
 click first time url will be ..../index.html#
again reload with this then it works. 2nd time it's working). when i load url in mobile and try to test it's not working.

Here is my code in header.html:

```
<div class="menuSet" style="background-image: url('img/image67.JPG');">
<nav class="top-bar row changedWmiddle" data-topbar style="background-image: url('img/image67.JPG');height:44px;"> 
   <ul class="title-area setMenu"> 
      <li class="name"> 
        <h1><a href="#" class="setMenu1">&nbsp;</a></h1> 
      </li> 
      <!-- Remove the class "menu-icon" to get rid of menu icon. Take out "Menu" to just have icon alone --> 
      <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon setMenu2">
        <a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a>
      </li> 
   </ul> 
   <div class="top-bar-section">
     <!-- Left Nav Section --> 
     <ul class="left row" style="width:98%;"> 
       <li class="setMenu3" style="min-width:16.43%;background-image:url('img/image67.JPG');"><a href="http://ec2-54-178-189-98.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/SamePage_Website(without_comment)/" class="setMenu5" style="background-image:url('img/image67.JPG');"><img src="img/image68.JPG"></a></li> 
       <li class="setMenu4" style="min-width:16.43%;background-image:url('img/image67.JPG');"><a href="http://ec2-54-178-189-98.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/SamePage_Website(without_comment)/Reason_For_Change.html" class="setMenu5" style="background-image: url('img/image67.JPG');"><img src="img/image69.JPG"></a></li>
       <li class="setMenu4" style="min-width:16.43%;background-image:url('img/image67.JPG');"><a  href="http://ec2-54-178-189-98.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/SamePage_Website(without_comment)/customer.html" class="setMenu5" style="background-image: url('img/image67.JPG');"><img src="img/image70.JPG"></a></li>
       <li class="setMenu4" style="min-width:16.43%;background-image:url('img/image67.JPG');"><a href="http://ec2-54-178-189-98.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/SamePage_Website(without_comment)/company.html" class="setMenu5" style="background-image: url('img/image67.JPG');"><img src="img/image71.JPG"></a></li>
       <li class="setMenu4" style="min-width:16.43%;background-image:url('img/image67.JPG');"><a href="http://ec2-54-178-189-98.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/SamePage_Website(without_comment)/motto.html" class="setMenu5" style="background-image: url('img/image67.JPG');"><img src="img/image72.JPG"></a></li>
       <li class="setMenu4" style="min-width:16.43%;background-image:url('img/image67.JPG');"><a href="http://ec2-54-178-189-98.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/SamePage_Website(without_comment)/recruit.html" class="setMenu5" style="background-image: url('img/image67.JPG');"><img src="img/image73.JPG"></a></li>
     </ul> 
   </div> 
 </nav>
```

I included header.html in my index.html and linked script like.

at starting of the page:

```
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
```

at bottom:(before  tag)

```
   <script src="js/foundation/foundation.js"></script>
   <script src="js//foundation/foundation.topbar.js"></script>
   <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
   <script>
      $(document).foundation();
   </script>
```

Here is the link of my url
http://ec2-54-178-189-98.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/SamePage_Website%28without_comment%29/index.html

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

foundation.min.js includes all the foundation js.

You need to use **either** "foundation.min.js" **or** "foundation.js, foundation.topbar.js, etc".

Reference: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/javascript.html

```
<script src="/js/foundation.min.js"></script>

<!-- or individually -->

<script src="/js/foundation.js"></script>
<script src="/js/foundation.alert.js"></script>
<!-- ... -->
<script src="/js/foundation.dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="/js/foundation.tab.js"></script>
```

The trouble you're experiencing could be coming from having both js files loaded.
Try just having one set loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem is with modernizr.js, to test it you can remove  foundation will work as expected.